# PhpStorm corrupting git with [conflicted]

Tags: git, intellij-idea, phpstorm

PhpStorm seems to be littering my codebase by postfixing files with `[conflicted]`, including files like `HEAD`, `index`, etc in the `.git` folder.

This in turn, corrupted my git repo, and I had to manually rename corrupted files in the `.git` folder.

Is there a setting I can make to prevent PhpStorm from postfixing files?

Comment: Why do you think it is PhpStorm creating these files specifically? Do you have any synchronisation configured for these files, inside or outside PhpStorm - e.g. PhpStorm's "deployment" feature, or a cloud sync service like OneDrive or Google Drive?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the backup software was causing this!